# find - folder isn't excluded and sed corrupts git index because of it

Tags: git, unix, sed, find

i want to exclude the `.git` folder from a `find` because `sed` always corrupts the `git` index file. My script is:

```
folder_root="my-files/files"

# change text in files
find $folder_root/ -type f -and -not -path $folder_root/.git -print0 | LC_ALL=en_US.CP437 xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i '' -e 's/fromthis/tothis/g'
```

and still `git index` gets corrupt:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-path "$theme_root/.git"` matches only that specific directory, not files within that directory.  Try instead

```
find "$folder_root/" -name .git -prune -o -type f -print0 | ...
```

The `-prune` action stops `find` from descending into a directory, so it will do what you want and will be faster as well.